How can I rotate two subsequent proofs from ebproof?
Due to quite an extensive proof within the ebproof environment, I have to both rotate and split the proof into two parts, so that it fits the page vertically. Ideally, the two blocks form a column and this column is rotated. Using \rotatebox{90} does rotate but ignores the new line and lines up the two environments next to each other. How can this be overcome?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
I would like to rotate this:\\\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}
\\\\
And I get this:\\\\
\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}
}

\end{document}




since ebproof already boxes the trees, I figured you should be able to rotate that box directly. you can use \rewrite{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{\box\treebox}} as the last line of the proof to rotate the box the tree is in. but I can't figure out how to get the box dimensions in order to adjust the horizontal spacing between the proofs appropriately.

\rotatebox is a single box tag, if you want to introduce any breaking content, then need to place those to \vbox or \parbox or minipage, and the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
I would like to rotate this:\\\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}
\\\\
And I get this:\\\\
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}\\
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
  \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
  \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
\end{prooftree}
}}

\end{document}



Rotate a tabular contiaining the proof trees.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
    \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
    \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
  \end{prooftree}\\[4ex]
  \begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{ &\vdash A, B, C }
    \hypo{ D &\vdash E }
    \infer2{ A, B, D &\vdash C, E }
  \end{prooftree}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}


